# New .bib-field fullauthor to be used instead of author

Tags: biblatex, options

In an extremely long bibliography it can be quite annoying to have the same author with a somewhat different name in each entry, especially if the publications appear as a list under the name of the author. On the other hand we need the correct data as they appear on the publications.

So I want an optional field, let's call it `fullauthor`, where I simply add up all information from the single entries. For my working bibliography I want to be able to set `fullauthor = true` as option to `biblatex`, else I will do nothing, in which case the `fullauthor`-field is just ignored.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=english,ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Ligatures=Common}
\setmainfont{TeX GyrePagella X}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Ligatures=TeX]
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,sortlocale=auto,sorting=nyvt,%
            bibencoding=utf8,backend=biber,ibidtracker=constrict,%
            idemtracker=constrict,clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex,type=file]{fullauthorname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{fullauthorname.bib}
@Article{Dude:White,
  author =   {{The Dude}},
  sortname =     {Dude},
  gender =   {sm},
  % fullauthor =     {Lebowski \mkbibbrackets{Slakyech}, \RN{2}
  %                 \mkbibparens{\mkbibquote{The Dude}},
  %                 Jeff\mkbibbrackets{rey} \mkbibbrackets{Robert}},
  sortname =     {Lebowski, Jeffrey},
  title =    {Making White Russian Even Better},
  journaltitle = {Slackers Quarterly},
  year =     1973,
  volume =   3,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {7-32}
}

@Thesis{Lebowski:Writing,
  author =   {Lebowski, \RN{2}, Jeffrey R\mkbibbrackets{obert}},
  gender =   {sm},
  % fullauthor =     {Lebowski \mkbibbrackets{Slakyech}, \RN{2}
  %                 \mkbibparens{\mkbibquote{The Dude}},
  %                 Jeff\mkbibbrackets{rey} \mkbibbrackets{Robert}},
  title =    {On Not Writing Anything at All},
  type =     {phdthesis},
  institution =  {University of Los Botellos},
  year =     1970,
  location =     {Los Angeles},
  pagetotal =    {1}
}

@Unpublished{Lebowski:Letter,
  author =   {Jeff Lebowski},
  gender =   {sm},
  % fullauthor =     {Lebowski \mkbibbrackets{Slakyech}, \RN{2}
  %                 \mkbibparens{\mkbibquote{The Dude}},
  %                 Jeff\mkbibbrackets{rey} \mkbibbrackets{Robert}},
  title =    {Leave me alone \mkbibbrackets{Letter to Maude
                  Lebowski}},
  date =     {1974-09-06},
  location =     {Los Angeles}
}
\end{filecontents}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly should happen if you set `fullauthor=true`? Is the field simply shown in the bibliography instead of the `author`? What about citations? What about the `dashed` option, etc. etc.?

Comment: Would `sortname` help?

Comment: Yes, it is to be used instead of `author`, the publications should appear as dashed list under the "fullauthor". I haven't thought about citations as in my case this is only for the bibliography, in the example above Lebowski or J. Lebowski would do it.

Comment: `sortname` doesn't help, as in 20 publications the author could still show up in 5 variants.

Comment: But of course you would want all citations with the same `fullauthor` to have the same citation label even though the `author` might differ?

Comment: As the real cases are MUCH less extreme than my construed sample, I can say yes. The `fullauthor` should be `Lebowski, \mkbibbrackets{Slakyech} \RN{2} \mkbibparens{\mkbibquote{The Dude}}, Jeff\mkbibbrackets{rey} \mkbibbrackets{Robert}`, which `biblatex` should turn into "Lebowski" or "J. Lebowski" or "J. Lebowski II".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a Sourcemapping. Give `fullauthor` for the full name in the bibliography and `fullciteauthor` for the name in citations. Then

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=fullauthor, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=fullciteauthor, final]
      \step[fieldset=shortauthor, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

together with

```
@Article{Dude:White,
  author         = {{The Dude}},
  gender         = {sm},
  fullauthor     = {Lebowski \mkbibbrackets{Slakyech}, \RN{2}
                    \mkbibparens{\mkbibquote{The Dude}},
                    Jeff\mkbibbrackets{rey} \mkbibbrackets{Robert}},
  fullciteauthor = {Jeff Lebowski},                   
  title          = {Making White Russian Even Better},
  journaltitle   = {Slackers Quarterly},
  year           = 1973,
  volume         = 3,
  number         = 2,
  pages          = {7-32}
}
```

gives you what you want.

It would be much more complicated to make `fullauthor` a replacement of `author` in the `biblatex` level.